# How to redirect user back to start if they enter an incorrect input

Tags: matlab

I am really new to this. This falls under my else statement but i would like to redirect it back to the start.  I was thinking along the lines of 
'''

```
false = input('You have entered an invalid number .Please try again and enter correct the unit (1-3) you wish to convert: ');

while ~x ==1 || x== 2|| x||3

     x = input('Enter the unit (1-3) you wish to convert: ');

end
```

'''

Comment: The question seems to be unclear. Can you elaborate what you'd like the program to do when the input is correct and when the input is wrong?

Comment: so I have given my user 3 options to enter 1, 2 or 3. To conduct this I used if else statements. In the last component of this I want include if my user does not input the correct value -example :4 , the command window will state that hey this is wrong and will repeat the question and connect it back to the start of the code. if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement requires `&&` and not `||` if you're checking for wrong inputs. This should work.

```
isInputWrong = true;
while (isInputWrong)
  x = input('Enter 1, 2, or 3: ');
  isInputWrong = (x ~= 1 && x~=2 && x~=3);
  if (isInputWrong)
    disp('Your input is wrong');
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
while x<1 || x>3 
   x = input('You have entered an invalid number. Please Enter the unit (1-3) you wish to convert: '); 
 end
```

Comment: This solution allows 1.1, 2.7, exp(1), etc. to work, which it sounds like you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I like `any` for this:

```matlab
while ~any(x, [1 2 3]) % Read: "while x doesn't match any in [1 2 3]"
    x = input('You have entered an invalid number.  Please enter the unit (1-3) you wish to convert: ');
end
```